# Core Data NSValidation error 1620

Tags: ios, core-data, save

I'm getting a "failed to save" error, no. 1620, when I try the following:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

CustomObject *objToInsert = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CustomObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];

objToInsert.variable1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0];
objToInsert.variable2 = [NSDate date];
objToInsert.variable3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"failed to save with error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

This same logic works just fine when saving other NSManagedObject-subclass objects to the managedObjectContext. The 1620 error is listed as being a "number too small" validation error, but there's clearly nothing wrong with the numbers I'm inputting. The three variables are defined in my data model as Float, Date and Integer 16, though I'm not sure whether that's 
relevant.

The Core Data stack is all present and correct and as I said, works just fine with other insertion logic. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: turns out from the error output that Core Data is trying to save a completely different NSManagedObject subclass, which I work with earlier in execution but not in this method call. Why would this be?

Comment: Have you double-checked that you did not set a "Minimum Value" in the Core Data Inspector for the attributes?

Comment: If you log `[error description]` instead of `[error localizedDescription]`, then you should see something like `NSValidationErrorKey=...`, `NSValidationErrorValue=...` which should help to localize the problem.

Comment: Yep - no minimum or maximum values set. But good suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output of the complete `[error description]` anyway?

Comment: Another great suggestion. Here's the output: `failed to save with error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1620 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1620.)" UserInfo=0x17b35180 {NSValidationErrorObject=<AnotherEntity: 0x8d9d470> (entity: AnotherEntity;` - looks like it's trying to save another entity altogether... Weird.

Comment: The 1620 error appears to be coming from this attempt to save a completely different NSManagedObject subclass, which I work with elsewhere but not in this particular method. Which explains why there's a validation error. But why is it trying to save a completely different object?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18478/discussion-between-martin-r-and-beko)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, the solution was partly as suggested by Martin R (see comments) but for a completely different entity. It appears that if a required minimum value is set for any other entity in the data model, and that entity is modified and saved at some prior point, any subsequent saves to other entities will cause an error. This does not seem to be sensible - maybe I'm doing something wrong elsewhere? - but removing the minimum value requirement did solve this particular problem.